# How to delete documents from index with query using jest elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, exchangewebservices, elasticsearch-jest

I am trying to delete documents from elastic search which have certain criteria to filter from the index using `deleteQueryBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about deleteQueryBuilder. However, if you are able to search your record (as you mentioned, some criteria), then replace your GET/PUT/POST etc to DELETE only which will delete your filtered records.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for deleting entire index.i think there is no possibility of deleting documents

```
1.you can delete using id
$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1'

2.or delete entire index

$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/'
```

Comment: I have to filter the documents using match query

Comment: match all returns all fields

Comment: There is a possibility with Delete.Builder to delete only one document using the id of the document. But I would like to filter with particular field which is not Id, a normal field.

Comment: you can delete any document with their id. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html

Comment: check it for deleting indices .  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html

Comment: I would like to filter with particular field which is not Id, a normal field.

Comment: I don't want to delete entire index,but a single object in it.

Comment: check this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html

Comment: Yes, I did that. But we have DeleteByQuery, I want to use that.which is here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/delete-by-query-usage.html with Jest

Answer (score 0):

In Jest I you want to use the:

`DeleteByQuery.Builder(query)`

method .. the Delete builder method is for id's only